# VB.NET SQL - Datagridvew Counting Same Rows

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

Hi i have the following to populate a datagridview table which works no problem, but the fact it returns, multiple entries of the same, i would like it to count the quantites and add them together. How would i do that?

```
        connect()
        DataGridView_b1.AutoGenerateColumns = True

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pcb, faultcode, component, quantity, type FROM [sqlcnvfaultentry] WHERE date = '" & breakdown_date.Value & "' and line = '" & breakdown_combo_line.Text & "' and hour = '" & breakdown_combo_hour.Text & "' and type = 'Process'"

        Dim dataAdapter_b1 = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con.ConnectionString)
        Dim table_b1 As New DataTable()
        table_b1.Locale = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
        dataAdapter_b1.Fill(table_b1)
        Me.breakdown_bindingsource_dpmop.DataSource = table_b1

        DataGridView_b1.DataSource = breakdown_bindingsource_dpmop
        DataGridView_b1.Columns(0).HeaderText = "PCB:"
        DataGridView_b1.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Fault Code:"
        DataGridView_b1.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Component:"
        DataGridView_b1.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Quantity:"
        DataGridView_b1.Columns(4).HeaderText = "Type:"

        breakdown_dataselected.Text = "Current Data Range: " & breakdown_date.Value.Date & " for Line " & breakdown_combo_line.Text & " at " & breakdown_combo_hour.Text
        Label_dpmo.Text = "DPMO(p) Data:"

        disconnect()
```

I've attached a pic of what i want to aim for (bottom pic) and the top is what im getting.

Any help would be great.

Cheers,
Pete

[image: Pic]

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Answer (score 0):

YOu are looking for [`group by` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx):

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT pcb, faultcode, component, 
                   SUM(quantity) as quantity, type 
                   FROM [sqlcnvfaultentry] WHERE ...
                   GROUP BY pcb, faultcode, component,  type"
```

Also, be careful with sql injection. [Use parametrized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3).